# Python error when setting up QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to set up Qgis to Python but when I run Python I got this error

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system
>   codec ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'  Current thread
>   0x00002b14 (most recent call first):

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/42512817/4699904

Comment: I look at it but when i remove the PYTHONHOME so python can run properly but if i do that qgis will not work. I did try somaby way to get qgis work on python but I sitll can not make it

Comment: What version of qgis are you using ? and what are the values of PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables ?

Comment: It my fault I use Python 37 32 bit so it doesnt work. I change it to python 37- -64bit and it work. Thank you guys very much for help